# CUDA Intergration, access violation

Tags: c++, math, cuda

Hello i am trying to implement an intergration function, in cuda, but i keep getting an access violation in the kernel, and i just can't see why!

```
#include <iomanip>    
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#define R 10000
#define leftBound 1.0
#define rightBound 3.0
#define P 10

#define threads 512
#define MaxBlocks 65535

__global__ void cudaKernal(float *M, int x, int leftbound, float width)
{
    unsigned int index = blockIdx.x * threads + threadIdx.x;
    while(index < x)
    {
        int x = leftBound + width*index;
        M[index] = (float)((exp(-pow((float)x,2))*cos((float)(P*x))) * width);

        // Next run
        index += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main ()  
{    
    float width = (rightBound - leftBound) / R;
    int x = ceil((rightBound - leftBound) / width);
    float total = 0; 

    // Trick for celin the total blocks
    int TotalBlocks = (x+threads)/threads;
    if(TotalBlocks > MaxBlocks)
        TotalBlocks = MaxBlocks;

    float *dev_M;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_M, x*sizeof(float));

    cudaKernal<<<TotalBlocks,threads>>>(dev_M, x, leftBound, width);

    float *M;
    cudaMemcpy( M, dev_M, x*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(dev_M);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) { 
        printf("M[i]=%f", M[i]); 
        total += M[i]; 
    }    

    printf("The integral is: %f", total); 
    scanf_s("%f",123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indicate exactly where the access violation occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't allocated any memory for M at host. This will solve the problem:

```
float *M = (float*)malloc(x*sizeof(float));
```

Answer (score 3):

The only access violation I see in your code is in line:

```
while(index <= x)
```

shouldn't it be:

```
while(index < x)
```

because you exactly allocated `x` elements for `dev_M` and indexes should be in `[0..x-1]`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is index < x, but here is the kicker, it workes for while(index < x-1) but not while(index < x) and i just can't see why!

Answer (score 2):

The access violation is probably in your host code here:

```
float *M; 
cudaMemcpy( M, dev_M, x*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
cudaFree(dev_M);
```

You are doing a memory transfer onto `M`, but is isn't allocated anywhere I can see.